Man wrongly convicted to death penalty, saved at the end
I found this site after googling for hours trying to find this movie that's are stuck in my head. It has been years since I have seen them and something recently made me think of them. Since then I can't get them out of my head, and want to watch them again.
Plot
An African American man is convicted of murder of a gas station/convenience store clerk who is pregnant. You find out that he was in the bathroom at the time of the killing and when he walked out and found her dead, he panicked and ran, causing him to look guilty. Witnesses saw him running from the scene so he was quickly convicted. I believe he was on Death row for many years before it came time for execution, and it was at this time that a report or journalist started investigating the crime. She, found lots of evidence and eventually finds out the truth. That the kid/man who killed the girl is dead already. But this proves the man in prison is innocent. Now she's trying to race against time to save him before the execution. In the end, she does. I believe the last scene is the two walking down a street at night, hand in hand.
I believe the movie might be from the late 90's or early 00's. It seemed like a well budgeted movie and I believe the main characters are decently famous. I have done a fair amount of looking around and keep coming up with this David Gale movie, which is not it. I'm pretty sure I saw it on TNT a few years back.
I know it's not much to go on, but I am going to lose my mind if I don't figure this out. I hope someone out there can help identify this movie. Please and thanks.

This sounds like Clint Eastwood's 1999 movie True Crime:

Steve Everett, Oakland Tribune journalist with a passion for women and alcohol, is given the coverage of the upcoming execution of murderer Frank Beachum. His attractive colleague Michelle died in a car accident the night before. Bob Findley, Steve's boss and husband to Steve's current affair, wants him dead and gone as soon as possible. When Steve stumbles across the possibility of Frank Beachum being innocently on death row, Bob feels his time to have come. Now Steve only has a few hours left to prove the innocence of Frank and to be right with this theory, as he definitely will be history if he's not.

I remember many others of your details. The pregnant supermarket saleswoman that is murdered, the man hiding in the bathroom during the murder, the already dead actual murderer. The end is slightly different but similar, Clint Eastwood, the jounralist who saved the man, sees him walking with his family across the street.

That's it! Wow, I think I even saw that title in my search but skimmed over it. Thanks so much. I'll edit out the second movie and create a new question.

Yep, I wasn't positive if it was a female journalist, so I wasn't sure on the ending. But you nailed it. He was with his family. :D
